# Stm32 Blue Pill Internal reference voltage Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, stm32

I want to use the internal reference voltage (1.2V) of stm32f103 blue pill using Arduino IDE. I searched the whole internet but couldn't find anything. I need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Did the whole internet include the datasheet for the chip?

Comment: Link to the core you're using, please. It *should* implement `analogReference(INTERNAL)` or something similar.

Comment: Maybe this will help a little: http://www.efton.sk/STM32/STM32_VREF.pdf (usualy it can be used to compute VREF+ or VDDA, as it can't be used directly as ADC reference)

Comment: And (different family, but it should be similar) https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkePgSAJ/use-adc-with-internal-vref-stm32l151

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of using the internal 1,2v reference as the ADC reference. (in the same way that you can do on an AVR)
You can only use the ADC to read the internal vref, and use that value to adjust the next ADC reading you take. Like a compensation factor.